# Vue 3 Composition API : access an array of object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an array in external json file "West.json"

```
{
    "west" : [
        {
            "id" : 1, 
            "state": "CA"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2, 
            "state": "AZ"
        },
        {
            "id" : 1, 
            "state": "WA"
        }
    ]
}
```

in a vue file, I import the json file, then how I can make a new array only with the value of "state"?

I can access to a value like this

```
import { west } from "../json/West.json"

const state = computed(() => {
     return west[0].state
```

I want get something like this, iterate [0]

```
{"state": [{"CA"}, {"AZ"}, {"WA"}]}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have an object like `{"CA"}` without a key, so you have to put a key like `[{state: "CA"}, {state: "AZ"}]`, you can do this:

```
return { state: west.map(item => ({state: item.state}))}
```

or accept it like this `["CA", "AZ"]` so you can do this:

```
return { state: west.map(item => item.state)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aous Mohammad!! it works. I have to study Javascript fundamentals more...